# How To make my blogger blog AMP responsive

Tags: html, blogger, amp-html

Please tell me how to implant AMP in my blogger blog. On google their is lots of article about steps to make blogger AMP . But non of them are effective as even after installing the code AMP search console not detect my site as valid AMP page.
Please help me.

Comment: Please tell us what you exactly tried to do until now.

Comment: I have read this (https://www.google.com/amp/s/blogcheater.com/setup-google-amp-blogger-site/amp/) article and applied it but I think it has some error as blogger not accept these changes the problem is in HTML tag and viewport I have to put /> at the end of html and viewport code even though it not make my blogger blog a valid AMP page. On google every one just copied  other article without checking if it work or not. Please help me . My blog http://shouttolearn.blogspot.com/